# Why does opencv's recoverPose return a non origin position when identical point vectors are supplied?

Tags: opencv

By accident I tried estimating the relative position of an image to itself (don't ask). I would expect a result of 0 translation and 0 rotation.

Surprisingly, I get a non-zero translation result. In fact I get a rather significant result: `.0825 -0.0825`.

In essence my code is as follows:

```
cv::Point2d pp(u0, v0);
        cv::Mat R, t, mask;
        cv::Mat E = cv::findEssentialMat(points1, points2, focal, pp, cv::RANSAC, 0.999, 1.0, mask);
        cv::recoverPose(E, points1, points2, R, t);
```

In the above code, t != 0. My question is: is a non-zero result for recoverPose valid when points1 and points2 are identical? If so, why?

Comment: what happens if you reduce the max distance threshold? To answer your question you will probably have to look at how the 5-point solvers work/behave for identical point pairs.

Comment: The essential matrix is not well-conditioned in that case.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger is there a way of determining whether the essential matrix is well conditioned?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number

Comment: For the 8-point algorithm you can check the condition number of the correspondence matrix before SVD as Micka says. I don't know if this applies to the 5-point algorithm that OpenCV uses. Anyway, there are cases in which the structure of the scene doesn't allow you to get a valid essential matrix (pure rotation, for example), and you need some other model, such as a homography. Search for GRIC score to read about one way to decide on essential matrix or homography.

Comment: @Micka FYI I dropped the distance threshold down to 0.1. Doing so didn't have an impact on this case.

Answer (score 1):

From [decomposeEssentialMat](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#decomposeessentialmat) documentation:
"By decomposing E, you can only get the direction of the translation"

And the translation vector is constructed in such a way that the norm of the translation is equal to 1.

Comment: Can you link the document in your answer with the hyperlink feature?

Comment: update your answer with the documentation link.So that it will be useful for others.